# Insert Statement with multiple select statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
insert into students_learn_subjects(student_id,subject_id) 
select max(id) from students, subject_id from classes_have_subjects where class_id = 5)
```

I want to insert values in table but retrieve these values from other table. With this query i am getting this error. The second select statement return multiple values but the first one only one

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"

> LINE 2: select max(id) from students, subject_id from classes_have_s...

Comment: You specified two fields in insert and one field in the select

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO students_learn_subjects (student_id, subject_id) 
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM students),
    subject_id
FROM classes_have_subjects
WHERE class_id = 5;
```

This assumes that the query against the `classes_have_subjects` table would return more than one record.  The max query against `students` must, by definition, always return a single scalar value, so it can sit in separate subquery.